# Top 1 por cada grupo de un Group by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tsql, group-by

Tengo una tabla similar a esta 
CancelLog

```
|ID| membrecia| User    | DateCancel  | Motivo |
| 2| 1        | uS1     | 7/29/2011   |  ...   |
| 3| 1        | uS2     | 7/30/2011   |   ...  |
| 6| 1        | uS1     | 8/02/2011   |   ...  |
| 1| 2        | uS1     | 7/28/2011   |   ...  |
| 4| 2        | uS2     | 7/30/2011   |  ....  |
| 5| 2        | uS3     | 8/01/2011   |    .   |
| 6| 3        | uS1     | 8/02/2011   |    .   |
```

y quisiera obtener El registro mas reciente de cada membresia es decir algo como esto

```
|ID| membrecia| User    | DateCancel  | Motivo |
| 6| 1        | uS1     | 8/02/2011   |   ...  |
| 5| 2        | uS3     | 8/01/2011   |    .   |
| 6| 3        | uS1     | 8/02/2011   |    .   |
```

Estaba haciendo algo similar a esto,

```
select l.membrecia, l.[USER] , l.DateCancel, count(*), max(l.DateCancel)
from CancelLog l
group by l.membrecia, l.[USER], l.DateCancel;
```

`count(*) y max(l.DateCancel)` solo los uso como informativos, no estarán en la consulta final

si me arroja los resultados mas recientes, pero si una membresia es "cancelada"* por varios usuarios distintos, me trae los datos de todos usuarios que la cancelaron

```
 |ID| membrecia| User    | DateCancel  | Motivo |
 | 3| 1        | uS2     | 7/30/2011   |   ...  |
 | 6| 1        | uS1     | 8/02/2011   |   ...  |
 | 1| 2        | uS1     | 7/28/2011   |   ...  |
 | 4| 2        | uS2     | 7/30/2011   |  ....  |
 | 5| 2        | uS3     | 8/01/2011   |    .   |
```

Quisiera obtener los registros como los que se muestran en la tabla 2.

*Durante la cancelación, el "Motivo" puede ser cambiado, y debido a este cambio es que se crea un nuevo registro en el log.

cambio del `motivo` "Baja temporal" a "Baja definitiva", por lo que me interesa solo el ultimo cambio sin importar el usuario, pero si necesito en los resultados al ultimo usuario que hizo el cambio.

Alguien sabe como podría obtener dichos registros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a los que ayudaron, pero logre resolverlo de la siguiente manera

```
select l.membrecia, l.[USER] , l.DateCancel
from CancelLog l
where id = (select top 1 lg.id from CancelLog lg
       where lg.membrecia = l.membrecia order by lg.id desc)
)
```

como pueden ver hice una subQuery, la cual obtengo el id mas reciente de una membresía dada, ordenándola de mayor a menor, obteniendo este id que este mas alto, lo comparo con el id de query principal y obtuve el resultado deseado

```
|ID| membrecia| User    | DateCancel  | Motivo |
| 6| 1        | uS1     | 8/02/2011   |   ...  |
| 5| 2        | uS3     | 8/01/2011   |    .   |
| 6| 3        | uS1     | 8/02/2011   |    .   |
```

Answer (score 4):

Lo que buscas se logra de forma muy sencilla usando la función ventana `row_number()`. No hay necesidad de usar tablas temporales y bucles, lo que es demasiado complicado y costoso para este tipo de consulta:

```
select c.ID, c.membrecia c.[User], c.DateCancel, c.Motivo
  from (select c.*,
               row_number() over (
                   partition by c.membrecia
                       order by c.DateCancel desc) as rn
          from CancelLog c) c
 where c.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, hice un ejercicio para poder obtener los datos que usted solicita de la manera en que las solicita, le adjunto una query de cómo lo logré, quizá le pueda servir. Saludos.

Acá la Query.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @contador INT = 1;
CREATE TABLE #temporal (id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), [User]  VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE  #datos (membrecia INT, [User] VARCHAR(20), DateCancel DATE, Motivo VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #temporal SELECT DISTINCT [USER] FROM CancelLog 

WHILE @contador < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temporal)+1
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #datos SELECT 
    membrecia, 
    [USER] ,
    DateCancel,
    Motivo
    FROM CancelLog 
    WHERE DateCancel = (SELECT MAX(DateCancel) FROM CancelLog WHERE [User] =  (SELECT [USER] FROM #temporal WHERE id = @contador)) 

    SELECT @contador +=1;
END
SELECT * FROM #datos
DROP TABLE #temporal
DROP TABLE #datos 
END
```

[image: Aquí se muestra la Query el resultado que entrega. Saludos.]